# Find and replace - should I use Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create a simple markup fix an I already did everything that I need like bold and italic etc.. But this is a bit harder than what I've done so far and I have no idea how to do this. Basically my input is very simple:

```
[imgGroup="group1"]
image1.jpg
[/imgGroup]
```

As you can see I pass a param that is `group1` and inside I have `image1`. I need to convert this into a link that has this image inside and group in rel tag like so:

```
<a href="image1.jpg" rel="group1" >
   <img src="image1.jpg" />
</a>
```

I think that I will need to use Regex for this problem, however I only know how to find something in between 2 tags, not so much for this problem... I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with C#.

Comment: Any reason for reinventing yet another markup instead of using already designed tools such as [markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)? Don't reinvent wheels. Don't use regexes. You will get pwned by hackers because it is close to impossible to foresee all possible cases.

Comment: Yes, there is. I am trying to pass images to use them with Shadobox.js plugin. It requires specific markup - http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html

Comment: Can there be multiple image filenames between the first and second `[imgGroup]` tags? If so, how would they be delimited? (Space, newline, etc.) Might help to show sample inputs and outputs with multiple images.

Comment: No, I think it will be much easier if there would be more than one image between [imgGroup]. I would just put many [imgGroup] with same group name.

Comment: What language will be doing the regex replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use named groups in RegEx to match, then you can just re-assemble them into the order you want:

```
var regex = new RegEx(("$1(\d\s)$2([a-z])");  // Set up your regex with named groups
var result = regex.Replace("inputstring", "$2 $1");  // Replace input string with the given text, including anything matched in the named groups $1 and $2
```

Be warned though, RegEx with things like Urls and HTML parsing can very, very quickly turn into a horror beyond your wildest dreams ;)

Good luck!

[Named groups for RegEx in dot net](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html)

Comment: Thanks, but since I will be the only one who will have access to this tag I think it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[imgGroup=" + "group1" + @"\]\s*(?<Content>\S*)\s*\[imgGroup\]");
var newValue = regex.Replace(oldValue, @"<a href=""$1"" rel=""group1"" ><img src=""$1"" /> </a> );
```

That should do what you've expected.